# ffMPEG "inttypes.h not found" error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, ffmpeg

While using the ffMPEG builds in Windows with Visual Studio 2010, I encountered the inttypes.h not found error.
Since searching through the internet led me to wrong solutions, I thought I'd put up the right solution here so that people can find it easily. Will be answering my own question soon.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The solution is to download [this file](http://code.google.com/p/msinttypes/downloads/list) and place the `inttypes.h` file either where Visual Studio can find it, or in the folder where ffMPEG's `common.h` is located. If you choose the latter, you'll have to change the `#include<inttypes.h>` line to `#include "inttypes.h"`.
Had got this solution from [here](http://libav-users.943685.n4.nabble.com/Libav-user-fatal-error-C1083-Cannot-open-include-file-inttypes-h-No-such-file-or-directory-td4655906.html).

Another solution which didn't work for me is to replace the `#include<inttypes.h>` with

```
typedef signed char  int8_t;
typedef signed short int16_t;
typedef signed int   int32_t;
typedef unsigned char  uint8_t;
typedef unsigned short uint16_t;
typedef unsigned int   uint32_t;
typedef signed long long   int64_t;
typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;
```

This solution was obtained from [here](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2007-January/027804.html).

Hope this helped.

Comment: As a note in my version of ffMPEG I also had a include for this in pixdesc.h as well. Additionally if you are only have the outer include folder listed in included directories it will be `#include "libavutil/inttypes.d"` instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
#ifndef HAS_INT_TYPES

#ifdef HAS_C99
  #include <stdint.h>
#endif

#endif
```