# inttypes.h header issue

Tags: c, visual-c++

nb: This question has been reduced many times, due to comments. 
Below now is presented minimum amount of code which generated the error. inttypes.h file was downloaded from here: [ffMPEG "inttypes.h not found" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266868/ffmpeg-inttypes-h-not-found-error)), which was thought to be the issue in the beginning.

```
//tlvlist.c

static int32_t test(somestruct *a);

/* Private method, adds tlv object to the list which contains raw binary data. */
int32_t int32_t test(somestruct *a)
{
    /* Some checks */
    if(a == NULL || bytes == NULL)
        return -1;

    /* Check if list is full */
    if(a->used == MAX_LIST_SIZE)
        return -1;

    /* Index to first free element in the list */
    int iIndex = a->used;

    // ...

    return 0;
}
```

errors:

```
 tlvlist.c
c:\users\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\tlv list\tlv list\tlvlist.c(21): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
c:\users\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\tlv list\tlv list\tlvlist.c(23): error C2065: 'iIndex' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\tlv list\tlv list\tlvlist.c(24): error C2065: 'iIndex' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\tlv list\tlv list\tlvlist.c(28): error C2065: 'iIndex' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\tlv list\tlv list\tlvlist.c(29): error C2065: 'iIndex' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\tlv list\tlv list\tlvlist.c(32): error C2065: 'iIndex' : undeclared identifier
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Impossible to tell without setting the code that causes the error. Try  reducing `tlvlist.c` to a *small* subset that exhibits the problem, and include the source file in your question.

Comment: @KeithThompson: please have a look if it helps

Comment: `<inttypes.h>` is a superset of `<stdint.h>`, and you don't appear to be using anything that's not in `<stdint.h>` (which apparently is available). Are you sure you need `<inttypes.h>`?

Comment: @KeithThompson: some macros inside inttypes.h which are used are greyed out, I think due to this: #if !defined(__cplusplus) || defined(__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS) // [   See footnote 185 at page 198

Comment: Your error messages refer to lines 56 to 67; the source file you've posted has only 38 lines (and compiles without error using gcc on Linux). Narrow it down to a *single* source file that exhibits the problem, and show us *that* exact source file and the exact error messages. If necessary, add comments to the source file indicating which lines are flagged by the error messages. If you're using the `PRIu16` et al macros, an alternative is to cast to, say, `unsigned long` and use `%lu`.

Comment: You provided a link to a question, one of whose answers provides a link to a zip file. Sorry, I'm not going to take the time to download and unzip that file to see what the `inttypes.h` file looks like. Maybe somebody else will. I'm also not going to figure out which lines in your source code correspond to the line numbers in the error messages. Read this: http://sscce.org/

Comment: @KeithThompson: line 56 was referring to this one:     int iIndex = a->used;

Comment: My previous advice stands.

Comment: @KeithThompson: what should I fix? line numbers?

Comment: You should post a small self-contained program that exhibits the problem (copy-and-paste the entire source file into the question), and you should show the error messages that you get when you compile that exact source file. Did you read http://sscce.org/ ?

Comment: The issue is most certainly in the code you didn't post...it compiles fine in MSVS C++ 2010 (once you fix the malloc casting), and you don't seem to use anything from "inttypes.h" in that code. Keith is trying to get you to do a little debugging and reduce your (presumably) large amount of code to a short example that can be easily posted here, assuming that you don't find and solve the issue yourself in the process.

Comment: @uesp: I know that I have already removed 70 % of tlvlist.c. THe only thing I didn't post is main.c. Errors come from tlvlist.c as seen in the errors in the end of my question.

Comment: Better, but now your question has 3 source files (which aren't clearly labeled) and 2 distinct sets of error messages. Ideally, if you could reduce it to a *single* short source file that reproduces the error (copy declarations from the header into the source file if necessary) *and remove everything else from the question*, it would be easier to follow what you're asking.

Comment: @KeithThompson: now? Is there alternative to those priu16 macros?

Comment: The question is still frankly a mess. Adding `main.c` is not helpful, since the compilation error doesn't depend on that file. You still have three source file in the question when one should do, and the relevant one is labeled "other source". "*Please see the issue - need to add some text.*" -- what?? As for an alternative to the `PRIu16` macros (not `priu16`; the names are case-sensitive), I suggested one about 35 minutes ago.

Answer (score 1):

Evidently, when compiling a C file in MSVS you need to have all variable declarations at the start of the function before any statement. For example:

```
int32_t Tlvlist_AddRawt(Tlvlist *a, uint8_t type, uint16_t size, const void *bytes)
{
    /* Index to first free element in the list */
    int iIndex;

    /* Some checks */
    if(a == NULL || bytes == NULL)
        return -1;

    iIndex = a->used;

    ...
}
```

I believe this is old C89 format and most C compilers now use C99 (or greater) which would permit variable declarations anywhere in the function. Renaming the file as CPP is another option for MSVS without moving the variable declarations to the top of a function, though it may raise other issues in the code.

Comment: That's exactly the problem; C added the ability to mix declarations and statements in 1999, but Microsoft doesn't implement the C99 (or C11) standard.

Comment: Your original code/question had mismatched error output and code which made it much (much) harder to diagnose. The ideal SO question has a short example code and the exact error output you get from that code. This makes it trivial for someone to copy/paste/compile and count lines to match errors with the code.

Comment: @pseudonym27: The downvote was mine, because the question at the time was verbose and confusing. Explaining the line mismatches was not in my opinion sufficient; you should have *corrected* them. The current version is in some ways better (thanks for that), but the error messages *still* don't match the posted source and the code sample is now *less* than minimal (it doesn't `#include` the necessary headers).

Comment: Referring to `a->used` *before* checking whether `a == NULL` is a bad idea. You need to declare `iIndex` at the top of the function and then assign a value to it later -- or you can introduce a new block scope to declare and initialize `iIndex` after the checks.

Comment: @pseudonym27: The code that was originally in the answer (it's been updated now) works fine *if ``a` is not null* (and I'm guessing it usually won't be). The point is that you need to check whether it's null before dereferencing it. With the check first, passing a null pointer means the function will safely return `-1`. With the check second, it will probably crash evaluating `a->used`, and the check is pointless.

Comment: Renaming the file with a `.cpp` suffix would mean you're compiling it as C++ -- which is a different (but closely related) language.