# installing h5py through pip on windows 7 (linker error)

Tags: python, windows, pip, linker-errors, h5py

I'm struggling to install h5py 2.5.0 on windows 7 on python 2.7.10. I had no luck finding a 64 bit package, only found 32-bit packages [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/h5py/2.5.0).

So I tried my luck using `pip install h5py`.
I installed the HDF5 1.8.16 package from hdfgroup.org and added its include directory to the windows environment (solved one issue). Then I downloaded *inttypes.h* as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266868/ffmpeg-inttypes-h-not-found-error) to solve the next issue.

However, now I'm stuck with this issue:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'h5py_hdf5.lib'
```

Any suggestions? (Or an alternative way to install h5py? or alternative hdf5 python interface?)

many thanks,
Dominic

Comment: I found a source with precompiled (not sure if python stuff needs to be compiled...?) packages for windows [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#h5py) which I could install through pip. It does the trick.